# Finding the sum of a numerical sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$. **Let S be its sum.**

To solve this series i used the series of functions $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$ of **Sum S(x)** and a radius of convergence **R=1**.

Now knowing the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$ and then taking the limit : **$\lim  _  {x\rightarrow1}$S(x)** would give us **S**.

Differentiating the Series of functions twice with respect to $x$ would lead us to a sum of a geomatric sequence  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{2n}= $=$1-x^2+x^4-x^6+...$! Can anyone help me in this from here with the integrating and getting the sum? since my integration didnt give me the true answer.

Comment: You are almost there. Note that the last sum is just $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: @graydad yes, of course -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}\right)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{1+x^2}\,dx $$
hence:

> $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\log 2}{2}}.$$

Comment: Thankyou that's the true answer but can you tell me how you reached the integral part from the given series?

Comment: Ah found it thankyouu

Comment: @MohamadMisto: I just exploited $\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$ and $\frac{1}{m+1}=\int_{0}^{1}x^m\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track! We know $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-x^2)^{n} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ for $x$ where $|x|<1$, and integrating the sum twice gives $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}+Cx +D$$ To pattern match this sum to your sum, we want $C = D = 0$. Now we want to integrate twice $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. The first integral is clearly $\arctan(x)+C$ where we know $C$ must be zero. So the problem (if you approach it this way) boils down to solving $$\int \arctan(x)  \text{d}x$$ You should be able to complete the second integral through integration by parts. When you're done simply deduce that your next integration constant is also equal to $0$ and plug in $x=1$. Or just evaluate your integral from $0$ to $1$ to avoid dealing with the constant.

Comment: Here was my problem in finding C couldnt find the way, do you have in mind a way  to find it?

Comment: @MohamadMisto I edited my answer, do you buy the reasoning?

Comment: Yes yes well thankyou, its now to find the integral of arctanx thankyou

Comment: @MohamadMisto It's a pretty easy one actually! Just make sure to let $dv = 1$. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\tan^{-1}(x)dxdx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}dxdx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$